# How to turn on vertical grid lines in barplot?

Tags: matlab, plot

How to turn on vertical grid lines in barplot?

```
grid on
grid minor
```

don't do it.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use the 'XGrid' and 'YGrid' properties of the current axes:

```
clc
clear

y = [75.995,91.972,105.711,123.203,131.669,...
     150.697,179.323,203.212,226.505,249.633,281.422];
figure;
bar(y);


set(gca,'XGrid','on')
set(gca,'YGrid','off')
```

which gives this:

[image]

Comment: @embert I just saw this post and was wondering if the answer solved your problem?